# dynamic or statically depicting data to speed up sending data

Tags: c#, performance

I've between 6000 to 6000,000 data and these data must be sent to a serial port . I send data to serial port every 3-5 ms. before sending data I must do some computation on it( for example taking sin , cos for some of data) and also depict data on a chart.every time I send a data I depict it on the chart and then compute the next data but this way is a little slow(and sometimes takes more time than 3-5 ms).

can the following ways speed up my program?are they proper ways?

> 1-first computing the movement chart completely(e.g
> 100sin(.0001*Index+10) for x=0 to 5000000) and storing it in an array
> then when I'm sending data to port ,I must find the data in an array
> and then depict and send it.
>
> 2-as above but storing it in a file and
> reading from file.

suppose this is my code:

```
namespace WPF_Toolkit_SpeedTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ChartItem> Items { set; get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #region winmm.dll functions
        int _counter = 0;
        public delegate void TimerEventHandler(UInt32 id, UInt32 msg, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 rsv1, UInt32 rsv2);

        /// <summary>
        /// A multi media timer with millisecond precision
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msDelay">One event every msDelay milliseconds</param>
        /// <param name="msResolution">Timer precision indication (lower value is more precise but resource unfriendly)</param>
        /// <param name="handler">delegate to start</param>
        /// <param name="userCtx">callBack data </param>
        /// <param name="eventType">one event or multiple events</param>
        /// <remarks>Dont forget to call timeKillEvent!</remarks>
        /// <returns>0 on failure or any other value as a timer id to use for timeKillEvent</returns>
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "timeSetEvent")]
        static extern UInt32 timeSetEvent(UInt32 msDelay, UInt32 msResolution, TimerEventHandler handler, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 eventType);

        /// <summary>
        /// The multi media timer stop function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="uTimerID">timer id from timeSetEvent</param>
        /// <remarks>This function stops the timer</remarks>
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern void timeKillEvent(UInt32 uTimerID);

        TimerEventHandler tim;//TimerEventHandler tim = new TimerEventHandler(this.Link);
        public void Link(UInt32 id, UInt32 msg, ref UInt32 userCtx, UInt32 rsv1, UInt32 rsv2)
        {
            _counter++;
            if ((_counter % 5) == 0) //if ((_counter % 10) == 0)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=>{
                    Items.Add(new ChartItem(_counter, 100*Math.Sin((.0002*_counter))));
                    if (_counter>1000)
                    {
                        Items.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }));
            }

            if (_counter > 10000)
            {
                timeKillEvent(id);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { button1.Content = stp.ElapsedMilliseconds; }));
            }
        }
        uint timerId;
        #endregion 

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Items = new ObservableCollection<ChartItem>();
            lineChart.ItemsSource = Items;

            Items.Add(new ChartItem(0, 0));
            tim = new TimerEventHandler(this.Link);
            uint rsv = 0;
            stp.Start();
            button1.Content = stp.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            timerId = timeSetEvent(1, 1, tim, ref rsv, 1);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    }
    public class ChartItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ChartItem(double t, double v)
        {
            time = t;
            myVar = v;
        }

        private double time;

        public double Time
        {
            get { return time; }
            set
            {
                time = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }

        private double myVar;

        public double Value
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set
            {
                myVar = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code shows only the depicting part,but in the same time I also send the data.

Comment: If you are depicting on a chart each time, I suspect that is the cause of the slow down. Maybe try batching expensive operations on to a separate thread to keep your throughput high.

Comment: Are you saying that you are moving up to 6 million data items though a serial port every 3-5ms?  Even if your data items are only 1 byte, that still requires a serial bit rate of at least 1000 Mbs.  What kind of serial port is this?!?

Comment: I send 22 byte every 5 ms to serial port and every time I add a point from these 22 byte on a chart. the time which I send data is 30-3000sec so I send about 30000/5 to 3000000/5 data.

Comment: That's a lot more reasonable.

Comment: Timings are pretty unrealistic.  You need to share the processor with all the other threads that run on the machine.  Losing the cpu for 45 msec or more is entirely normal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're combining I/O bound code and CPU bound code needlessly. I'd say the more proper approach would be to send the data asynchronously (and immediately) - async and await make this incredibly painless. Unless, of course, there's some reason why you want to have the two portions bound.

Also, it seems that your issue might be slightly more complicated, since there's no way a simple sin or cos would take you whole milliseconds. Have you tried profiling your application to find out where the real problem is?

For example, if you're recreating the graph on every step and showing it in some UI, you're going to get a massive slowdown. Do *not* let UI slow down your underlying communication. Instead, refreshing the UI should only be done once in a while, and ideally separate from the data flows underneath.

I find it really hard to believe that simple math operations would be enough to slow your code down this much. My computer can easily do over a hundred thousand of sin operations every millisecond - if you're doing this much while plotting a graph, you're doing something horribly wrong :D

Comment: If your computer can do 10 Million SIN calls a millisecond, then it is considerably faster than the average.  SIN is at *least* a 10 FLOP/100 OPs call, so that would be `10 FLOPs * 10 Million calls * 1000 ms/Sec = 100 GFLOPs`.  That's a PC I'd like to have on my desktop!

Comment: @RBarryYoung Oops. Look who forgot optimizations on when trying a simple benchmark :) I've changed the value to be more realistic, though it doesn't really change anything (100 thousand ops/sec are still more than enough unless you're doing something very wrong). Of course, my computer can easily do much more than 100 GFLOPs, but only on the GPU :D

Comment: Yes, now that [s]he's made clear what the actual rate is, 100K/sec is plenty.